# Updating optionMenu when pressed

Tags: python, list, tkinter, optionmenu

I searched all over the internet, and couldn't find
a way to update the options menu when it is pressed.
I should have a method that will run after the optionsMenu is pressed, like an actual button, such that the options are immediately updated according to the above method.
Is this even possible? if there isn't such a way, is there
a good alternative for this over Tkinter, which looks as good as optionsMenu?

Thanks!

Comment: What did you try? Please, spend some time reading ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["How do I ask a good question?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You will get better results by following the tips in those articles.

Comment: It is not clear what do you mean by *"update the options menu when it is pressed"*.

Comment: @acw1668 suppose there is a list of users and I want to update any time I press the chooseMenu to see who is connected. So when I press the chooseMenu, I mean when I click the chooseMenu I want it to run a method that updates the options.

Comment: *"press/click the chooseMenu"* Does it mean after you have selected an option in `chooseMenu` (an `OptionMenu` widget)? To be more clearly define your need, better provide a [mre].

Comment: @acw1668 No, it means that before you select something when you just click the menu to see what options you got.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `tkinter.OptionMenu` use [`tkinter.ttk.Combobox`](https://anzeljg.github.io/rin2/book2/2405/docs/tkinter/ttk-Combobox.html), to modify the list of values of a combobox simply change it's values attribute like so -:

```
def add_to_combobox(new_item) :
    combobox['values'].append(new_item)

combobox = tkinter.ttk.Combobox(master, option=value, ...)
combobox['values'] = ['my', 'new', 'list']
combobox.current() # Can pass as argument the index of the list to set as default
```

Now, to add a new item to the combobox simply call the `add_to_combobox` method with the new_item to insert.